# Access not configured youtube api v3 android

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am implementing android application which uses YouTube API v3

I have received "access not configured" all the time even if changing the project name in Google cloud APIs or changing the android key to browser key

I am searching about the subscribes that the user subscribes to

that is my all code

```
public class Youtube extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
 {

 private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
private static YouTube youtube;
GoogleAccountCredential credential;
GoogleCredential CREDENTIAL = new GoogleCredential();
com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube service;
final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
final String CLIENT_ID = "client key";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 SharedPreferences mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 String test = mPreferences.getString("USER_ACCOUNT_AUTH_PREF", null);
 AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()).invalidateAuthToken("com.google", test);
 final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
 AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()).getAuthTokenByFeatures(
   "com.google", "oauth2:https://gdata.youtube.com", null,this, null, null, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
            try {
                Bundle bundle = future.getResult();
                String acc_name = bundle
                        .getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                String auth_token = bundle
                        .getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);               

                System.out.println("name: " + acc_name + "; token: "
                        + auth_token);

                editor.putString("USER_ACCOUNT_PREF", acc_name);
                editor.putString("USER_ACCOUNT_AUTH_PREF", auth_token);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println( e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": "
                        + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, null);
   editor.commit();        

   String test2 = mPreferences.getString(
    "USER_ACCOUNT_AUTH_PREF", null);
   CREDENTIAL.setAccessToken(test2);
   credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(),
    Arrays.asList(Auth.SCOPES) );       
    credential.setSelectedAccountName(mPreferences.getString("USER_ACCOUNT_PREF",   null));
  youtube = new YouTube.Builder(
    transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(
    getPackageName()).setHttpRequestInitializer(CREDENTIAL)
    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(CLIENT_ID))
    .build();
   RetreiveFeedTask task= new RetreiveFeedTask();
   task.execute();

  }
 class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      try {
          try {
            YouTube.Subscriptions.List subscriber =  youtube.subscriptions().list("snippet");
                subscriber.setMine(true);
            subscriber.setKey(api key);
                subscriber.execute();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("subscribe exception");
        }
      }
      catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("exception");}
      return null;
      }}
 }
```

so now what can I do to get the subscribes that the user subscribes to ??

Comment: You shouldn't post developer key in question. It is very sensitive information.

Comment: but help me please if you know how to solve this problem

Comment: Sometimes key takes entire day to go live in production or become useful.